# Android draw rect with only curve one side on custom view

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view, android-drawable

i need this shape (rect or any ways) draw on `View` android. with only one curve side. with 1 solid color and transparent on curved side. how to draw this?

```
public class CurveView extends View {
     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         // how to ????
     }
}
```

like this:

[image]

thanks.

Comment: `canvas.drawPath(path, paint)`

Comment: Read the info on this page, [Android Path](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html), then write some code. If you encounter an error or an result different from what you expect, come back and ask a specific question.

Comment: @Alex android path and graphic is complex and need long time. can you help me to draw it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solution:

UPDATE:

```
public class MyView extends View {

    private Paint paint;
    private Path path;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {

        path = new Path();

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        paint.setShader(null);

        float width = getWidth();
        float height = getHeight();

        path.moveTo(0, 0);

        path.lineTo(0, height);

        path.lineTo(width, height);

        path.lineTo(width, 0);

        path.cubicTo(4*width/6, 3*height/4, 2*width/6, 3*height/4, 0, 0);

        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show the part where you define "paint" variable and "path"? Thanks.

Comment: @FaustinoGagneten updated done. check out. after write this rebuild your view.

Comment: Your answer is awesome. I just want to know how to make this view curvy from outside, I mean simply this view render curve as shown in picture in question. But I want to make reverse of it and both side ???

Comment: @HeisenBrg it's simple. you must change `path.cubicTo(....)` points and curve points for your ideal mind.